# using two different order by statements in one query

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider a column1 in a table has values 'A' or 'B' or null. if the Column1 has value 'A', a select query needs to be executed **ordered by column2**, else the select query needs to be executed **ordered by column3**.

Can you please help me to acheive this requirement via single query.

Answer (score 8):

Just a guess, have to be checked!

```
select *, decode (column1, 'A', column2, column3) as field_for_order
from your_table
order by field_for_order
```

Comment: You can put that decode directly into the `order by` clause. No need for the additional column.

Comment: +1 Can also use ANSI CASE expression: `order by case column1 when 'A' then column2 else column3 end`

Comment: @Tony Andrews Thank you for your ANSI example.

Comment: This won't work - you cannot refer to an alias in your SELECT clause in the ORDER BY clause. You *have* to use a_horse / Tony's suggestion, or wrap the query in a subquery and put the ORDER BY on the outside.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp Unfortunatelly I don't have right now access to an Oracle database. I will check that you told me next week and edit if necessary my answer.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp I have tested this select with Oracle 11 and it works correctly. I mean I refer to an alias in my SELECT clause in the ORDER BY clause and it is OK.

Comment: Thanks @skwllsp, you're right. My mistake - the restriction I was thinking of applies to GROUP BY, not ORDER BY.